# Как сделать чтобы кнопки перестраивались на новую строку в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qpushbutton, qsizepolicy

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы сделать виджет со множеством (10-100) кнопок с разным текстом внутри, так чтобы по размеру они могли занимать как 20 так и 200 пикселей.

Я хочу чтобы кнопки перемещались на новую строку когда упирались в край блока и подстраивались при растяжении окна, также как ведут себя слова в `QLable`.

Существует ли какой то способ это сделать?

Привожу пример кода:

```
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main = QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(100):
            btn = QPushButton(str(i),self.main_layout)
            btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue; margin: 0px; padding: 1px;")
        self.main.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.main.show()

MyApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, такие способы существуют. Один из них выглядит так:

```
import random
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLayout, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)
    

class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, margin=0, spacing=-1):
        super(FlowLayout, self).__init__(parent)

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
        self.setSpacing(spacing)
        self.itemList = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.itemList.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self.itemList)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList[index]
        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if index >= 0 and index < len(self.itemList):
            return self.itemList.pop(index)
        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self.doLayout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super(FlowLayout, self).setGeometry(rect)
        self.doLayout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QSize()

        for item in self.itemList:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        margin, _, _, _ = self.getContentsMargins()
        size += QSize(2 * margin, 2 * margin)
        return size

    def doLayout(self, rect, testOnly):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        lineHeight = 0

        for item in self.itemList:
            wid = item.widget()
            spaceX = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                QSizePolicy.PushButton,
                QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
            spaceY = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                QSizePolicy.PushButton,
                QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)
            nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
            if nextX - spaceX > rect.right() and lineHeight > 0:
                x = rect.x()
                y = y + lineHeight + spaceY
                nextX = x + item.sizeHint().width() + spaceX
                lineHeight = 0

            if not testOnly:
                item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = nextX
            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, item.sizeHint().height())

        return y + lineHeight - rect.y()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")
        
        flowLayout = FlowLayout()

        for i in range(100):
#            btn = QPushButton(str(i), self.main_layout)
            btn = QPushButton(f'{i}')
            btn.setFixedWidth(random.randrange(20, 200))
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=btn: print(btn.text()))
            btn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    background-color: blue; 
                    color: #fff;
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    background-color: #9999FF;
                    color: #ff7;
                }                
            """)
            flowLayout.addWidget(btn)         
        
        self.setLayout(flowLayout)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(800, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, Ваш класс хорошо работает! Можете подсказать как сделать чтобы отступов между кнопка совсем не было?

Comment: @Honeyloy , свойство `spacing` содержит расстояние между виджетами внутри макета. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop  Добавьте перед строкой `self.setSpacing(spacing)` строку `spacing = 0`